# Getting Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException in Selenium

Tags: java, maven, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Getting `"main" java.lang.NullPointerException` in Selenium

I am new to Selenium and I have started POM structure by following Youtube/Udemy tutorials.
Iam getting this error.

My POM class code :

```java
package Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Guru99Homepage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Guru99Homepage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void browserlaunch() {
        System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "/Users/saurabh.gupta/eclipse-workspace/Project/Driver/chromedriver");
        driver = new ChromeDriver();
    }

    public void openguruwebsite() {
        driver.get("http://demo.guru99.com/V4");
    }

}
```

2nd POM Class :

```java
package Pages;
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Guru99LoginPage {
    WebDriver driver;

    public Guru99LoginPage(WebDriver driver) {
        this.driver = driver;
    }

    public void username(String User_name) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='uid']")).sendKeys(User_name);
    }

    public void Password(String Pass) {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//input[@name='password']")).sendKeys(Pass);
    }

    public void clickat_loginbutton() {
        driver.findElement(By.xpath(" //input[@name='btnLogin']")).click();
    }
}
```

Test case :

```java
package TestCases;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import Pages.Guru99Homepage;
import Pages.Guru99LoginPage;

public class Guru99Login{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = null;
        Guru99Homepage homepage = new Guru99Homepage(driver);
        Guru99LoginPage lgnpage = new Guru99LoginPage(driver);

        //Browserlaunch
        homepage.browserlaunch();

        //WebsiteOpen
        homepage.openguruwebsite();
        //driver.manage().window().maximize();
        lgnpage.username("mngr47659");
        lgnpage.Password("123456@");
        lgnpage.clickat_loginbutton();
    }
}
```

"I am able to open browser but after that Iam getting the below error message"

```
INFO: Detected dialect: W3C
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at TestCases.Guru99Login.main(Guru99Login.java:31)
```

Please help me ,so that I can start pom structure with your support.

Thanks

Comment: you are getting error because when you instantiate page object classes, driver is null. what you need to do is instantiate the driver in your Guru99Login class

Answer (score 0):

In main function you have initialized **WebDriver driver=null;**.Instead make it as WebDriver driver;